# Not able to mount folders in dbfs

Tags: azure-databricks

I am not to access files in databricks file system. Databricks Runtime version 11.1 (includes Apache spark 3.3.0,scala 2.12) I have multiple csv files in file path like folder1/folder2/ledger1.csv

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to access files in DBFS?

Answer (score 0):

To mount DBFS you need to enable DBFS file browser in Workspace settings.

To enable DBFS file browser follow this path: `Settings> Workspace settings>DBFS File Browser`

Nested mounts are not supported. For example, the following structure is not supported:

•   folder1 mounted as /mnt/folder1

•   folder2 mounted as /mnt/ folder1/ folder2

Databricks recommends creating separate mount entries for each storage object:

•   folder1 mounted as /mnt/folder1

•   folder2 mounted as /mnt/folder2

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#--mount-object-storage-to-dbfs

Comment: you don't need to have DBFS file browser enabled to do the mounting